# KaliPi on raspberry pi 0

Tags: wifi, kali

I'm having some trouble in installing Kali distribution for raspberry on the Pi zero (no wifi) device.
Actually I think it is basically fine but empty, I only get the terminal version of Kali with more or less no package installed. This causes me troubles because I apparently cannot connect it to any wifi (or maybe I am just not able to install the Pi dongle through command line) to download missing packages.
Any suggestions? Which packages should I install in order to make my stock Pi dongle work with this distribution?

p.s. the pi dongle worked fine when I had the Raspian distro and required me no configuration, it was just plug and play